# Uniform handling of includes of OpenCL on MacOS and other platforms

Tags: include, opencl

On MacOS we use:

```
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
```

on other platforms like Linux and Windows we would write

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
```

My question is how to handle these uniformly. I am writing a set of OpenCL kernels and would like to give them to other people without saying 'oh and if you are not using MacOS change these lines to...'
Can this be handled in the makefile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this is to use preprocessor macros to check whether your code is being compiled on OS X or not. For example:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
```